# Node server is getting down with Error: write after end

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

We are streaming files from s3, its running well but sometime (randomly in few days) its gives error and node instance is getting down. our code is

```
s3Utils.headObject(assetId, function (err, metadata) {
        if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
          console.log("file not found on s3: ", assetId) ;

          res.send({"success":false, "message":"file not found on s3: "+ assetId});
        } else {
          var download_file_name = assetId;
          if(metadata.Metadata && metadata.Metadata.filename) {
            download_file_name = metadata.Metadata.filename;
          }
          if(metadata.ContentLength) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Length',metadata.ContentLength);
          }

          res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' +download_file_name);
          res.attachment(download_file_name);

          var fileStream = s3Utils.getObjectAsReadStream(assetId);
          fileStream.pipe(res);
        }
      });
```

we are getting below error in logs

```
    events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:166:12)
    at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:211:5)
    at IncomingMessage.ondata (_stream_readable.js:536:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:368:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:751:26)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:731:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Server is getting down after this error.
Please suggest.

Comment: Where is the res.write function, I think your problem is your code is 
trying to res.write after res.end, don't forget: node.js is a non-blocking async platform. Sometimes node.js excute it perfect and as you want because res.write is called normally if nothing takes time, So in your case i think when that error happens is when your code takes time to res.write

Comment: Hi @tyehia, we are not using res.write or res.end, we are piping the stream to the response. I have already added that code.
fileStream.pipe(res);